# Images not moving from one UNC to another UNC

Tags: powershell, copy, unc

I would add this to my other post, but I can't find it. I have been trying to copy images (JPG and JPEG) from one UNC (source) to two UNCs (destinations) that are three days old. I only need to copy the images, not the folders they are contained in.

I do not get any errors, the email received from the script tells me no images were copied. The destinations do not have any images copied to them and there are images in the source that are newer than three days from todays date. I am completely lost. I have been on Google all day trying to figure this out to no avail so far. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

```
$ImageLocation = "\\vdifiles\Print-Room\FileSrv\Barcode-Order"
$TestSite = "\\10.0.100.3\www2.varietydistributors.com\catalog\newpictures"
$LiveSite = "\\10.0.100.3\Variety Distributors.com\catalog\newpictures"
$WhenFileWritten = (get-date).AddDays(-3)
$IncludeFileTypes = "*.jpeg,*.jpg"
$LogFile = "C:\Temp\FilesCopied.log"

$EmailServer = "emailserver.me.com"
$EmailFrom = "fromme@me.com"
$AuthUser = "user"
$AuthPass = "pass"
$XHeaderInfo = "X-Header: This email was sent from Laservault."
$EmailTo = "tome@me.com"
$EmailSubject = "Barcode Images Summary."
$EmailBodySent = "Attached to this email is a log file of what images were copied from $ImageLocation to $TestSite and $LiveSite as well as sent to AS2 to send over to Order Stream."
$EmailBodyNotSent = "There were no files in $ImageLocation that matched $WhenFileWritten days old. So, nothing was sent to $TestSite, $LiveSite or AS2."

$TheImages = get-childitem "Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::$ImageLocation" -recurse | where-object {$_.Extension -eq $IncludeFileTypes -and $_.LastWriteTime -gt $WhenFileWritten -and $_.PsIsContainer -eq $false}

foreach ($Images in $TheImages) {
$FileCount = $Images.count

if ($FileCount -gt 0) {
    copy-item -path $Images.FullName -destination "Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::$TestSite" -force
    copy-item -path $Images.FullName -destination "Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::$LiveSite" -force

    write-host "$FileCount files were copied." 
    write-output $Images >> $LogFile
    \\vdifiles\blat$\blat.exe -attach $LogFile -to $EmailTo -s $EmailSubject -i $EmailFrom -body $EmailBodySent -server $EmailServer -u $AuthUser -pw $AuthPass -f $EmailFrom -x $XHeaderInfo
    remove-item $LogFile
} else {
    \\vdifiles\blat$\blat.exe -to $EmailTo -s $EmailSubject -i $EmailFrom -body $EmailBodyNotSent -server $EmailServer -u $AuthUser -pw $AuthPass -f $EmailFrom -x $XHeaderInfo
}   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your original post: [Copy-Item : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Path' because it is null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21170505/copy-item-cannot-bind-argument-to-parameter-path-because-it-is-null)

I copied my answer from there here:

---

The issue is with the `Get-ChildItem` not returning anything. It's a small problem because of the `-include` and `-exclude` parameters you are feeding into it. You are defining the variable like this:

```
$IncludeFileTypes = "*.jpeg,*.jpg"
$ExcludeFileTypes = "*.psd,*.tif,*.pdf"
```

The problem is that the `-include` and `-exclude` parameters are expecting a string array (`String[]`) what you are giving them is a straight string.

We can prove this, if you create a file with the name `"a.jpeg,a.jpg"`, the `get-childitem` cmdlt will return the file.

The solution is to change your `$IncludeFileTypes` and `$ExcludeFileTypes` variables to a string array, and it should return the results that you are expecting:

```
$IncludeFileTypes = "*.jpeg","*.jpg"
$ExcludeFileTypes = "*.psd","*.tif","*.pdf"
```

Answer (score 0):

The `where-object` is not finding any match for any files.

Amend `$IncludeFileTypes = "*.jpeg,*.jpg"` to `$IncludeFileTypes = @("*.jpeg","*.jpg")`

Then pass that array of file types into the `get-childitem` command using the `-include` Parameter (`-filter` only takes one filetype, as a string) and remove the `$_.Extension` check from the `where-object` command.

e.g.

```
$TheImages = get-childitem "Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::$ImageLocation" -recurse -include $IncludeFileTypes | where-object {$_.LastWriteTime -gt $WhenFileWritten -and $_.PsIsContainer -eq $false}
```

You are also checking the count of the wrong variable to get your file count, and it shouldn't be inside the `foreach` loop.

Get the file count, then if it's greater than zero, iterate through the list if files, copying them.

Try:

```
$FileCount = $TheImages.count  
if ($FileCount -gt 0) {  
foreach ($Images in $TheImages) {
```

And also
`write-output $TheImages >> $LogFile`

Instead of
`write-output $Images >> $LogFile`

Comment: Now, I am getting no email and no files are being copied from source UNC to destination UNCs. This is what I have:

Comment: $TheImages = get-childitem "Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::$ImageLocation" -include $IncludeFileTypes -exclude $ExcludeFileTypes -recurse | where-object {$_.LastWriteTime -gt $WhenFileWritten -and $_.PsIsContainer -eq $false}

Comment: $IncludeFileTypes = "*.jpeg","*.jpg"
$ExcludeFileTypes = "*.psd","*.tif","*.pdf"

Comment: Didnt see you last post about the "@". Ill try that and see what happens. So far, not working and no errors. Not going to give up even though frustrating.

Comment: Have updated my answer, spotted a couple of other issues that won't be helping. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

You are declaring the list wrong, it should be like this:

```
$IncludeFileTypes = @("*.jpeg","*.jpg")
```

Try searching with the -Include like this:

```
$TheImages = get-childitem "Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::$ImageLocation" -recurse -Include $IncludeFileTypes | where-object {$_.LastWriteTime -gt $WhenFileWritten -and $_.PsIsContainer -eq $false}
```

And check if the variable is empty after that:

```
if($TheImages -ne $null)
{
#move...
#send email...
#etc
}
```

Hope this solves your issue.